# XSL generic vertical table

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to write a XSL to transform my XML to a vertical table. I don't know about the existing elements. Suddenly there could appear an IBAN element, but it would be there for ALL books. The input is as follows:

```
<Library>
  <Book>
    <Title>Foo</Title>
    <ThisMaybeHere>Some Value</ThisMaybeHere>
    <DontKnowAboutThis>Also Value</DontKnowAboutThis>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Title>Bar</Title>
    <ThisMaybeHere>Some Value</ThisMaybeHere>
    <DontKnowAboutThis>Also Value</DontKnowAboutThis>
  </Book>
</Library>
```

**The desired output would be:**

```
Title             | Foo        | Bar
ThisMaybeHere     | Some Value | Some value
DontKnowAboutThis | Also Value | Also Value
```

**What I've tried so far:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/Library">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="//Book/*">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This leads to the following table:

```
<!-- First Book !-->
Title             | Foo
ThisMaybeHere     | Some Value
DontKnowAboutThis | Also Value
<!-- Second Book !-->
Title             | Bar
ThisMaybeHere     | Some Value
DontKnowAboutThis | Also Value
```

So it loops first through the books and then through the values. What would be a possible solution to get the desired output as stated above?

Many thanks!

Comment: Will each `book` element always have same child elements present? Or can some of the child elements be optional?

Comment: Yes, every book will have the same child elements present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution uses the element names of the first `Book`'s children as names for the first column. Then it uses the position of the current child as index over all `//Book`s with the expression `//Book/*[$pos]`.

This approach does only work if the order of the children is the same in every `Book` element. Otherwise it will fail.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/Library">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="Book[1]/*">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
          </td>
          <xsl:for-each select="//Book/*[$pos]">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```